# Replace part of a matrix by values of another matrix for specific coordinates

Tags: r, matrix, replace, dataframe

I have a matrix `A` with `i`,`j`,`z` values (`1:72`,`1:205`,`z`). I would like to replace the `z` values of the matrix `A` by the `z` values of a data frame `B`, and to put other non-`NA` values at 0.

Matrix `A`:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7 ... 205
1  999 999   0   0   0   0 1.7       0
2  999   0 0.3 1.2 4.3 2.1   0     3.8
...
72 999 999 999 999 999   0   0     2.5
```

Data frame `B`:

```
 i   j  z
 6   1  1
 3   2  1
```

What I would like:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7 ... 205
1  999 999   0   0   0   1   0       0
2  999   0   1   0   0   0   0       0 
...
72 999 999 999 999 999   0   0       0
```

I know how to replace a specific number by another like `A[A== 0]<-B`, but my second dataset is a 3 column data frame with only the `i`,`j` values of some points.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Is the first row of `B` really `c(1, 6, 1)`, instead of `c(6, 1, 1)` (your result matrix seems to suggest this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A[as.matrix(B[1:2])] <- B[[3]]
```

You can use the first two columns of `B` as a numerical index for `A`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and you answer. I tried your code, but it doesn't replace the A terms by the B terms in the A matrix, it creates a vector of numbers corresponding to the z column... Maybe I didn't understand what you told me to do ?

Comment: Thank you very much, in fact my problem was more difficult since I had to replace in a 3D array, but I did it for a matrix that I duplicated for each slice of my arry, and it works ! So A was an array and B a matrix, but now its ok. Thank you again !